# Export to gltf from blender with stretched textures

Tags: blender, gltf

I have the following object with textures:

[image]

But when I export it to a gltf it looks like this:

[image]

here is the way i texture it:
[image]

Has anybody the same problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: Yes, this question belongs on the Blender StackExchange, not here.  Also, see the Blender Manual's section on [exporting glTF with PBR textures](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html).